# Не знаю как текст введённый в textarea передать в другую textarea

Tags: javascript, html5, textarea

Есть такой код:

```js
    <script>
    let i, postText = [], preTextFrag = [];
    for (i = 0; i < preText.length; i++) {
    preTextFrag[i] = preText[i];
    if (preText[i] == '\n') preTextFrag[i] = ' ';
    postText += preTextFrag[i]
    }
    </script>
    <textarea class="pre" placeholder="Исходный текст"> 
    </textarea>
    <textarea class="post" placeholder="Перенесённый текст"> 
    </textarea>
```

Скрипт должен переменной `preText` присвоить значение, которое является текстом, введённым в `<textarea>` c классом `pre`. Затем значение переменной `preText` передаётся в программу, которая делает некоторые манипуляции с этим введённым текстом (заменяет переносы на пробелы) и возвращает этот преобразованный текст  в переменной `postText`. Вопрос в том, как значение переменной `postText` (преобразованный текст) вставить в `<textarea>` c классом `post`?

Comment: Покажите script.js, чтобы понять, что вы делаете там

Comment: Скрипт заменяет переносы строк на пробелы.
function (preText) {
    let i, postText = [], preTextFrag = [];
    for (i = 0; i < preText.length; i++) {
        preTextFrag[i] = preText[i];
        if (preText[i] == '\n') preTextFrag[i] = ' ';
        postText += preTextFrag[i]
    }
    return postText
}

Comment: Так надо было указать его содержимое в теле вопроса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
    // получаем элементы по классу с DOM
    const $pre = document.querySelector('.pre')
    const $post = document.querySelector('.post')
      
    // вешаем слушатель события на ввод  
    $pre.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
      $post.value = changeSourceText(event.target.value)
    });
        
    // функция принимает текст, дополняет его значением, и возвращает строку в верхнем регистре
    function changeSourceText(value) {
      const additional = ' bla bla'
      const result = value + additional
      return result.toUpperCase()
    }
```

```html
<textarea class="pre" placeholder="Исходный текст"></textarea>
<textarea class="post" placeholder="Перенесённый текст"></textarea>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 2):

```js
 document.getElementById("typeword").oninput = () => {
  const typeword = document.getElementById('typeword');
  const copyword = document.getElementById('copyword');

  copyword.value = typeword.value;
};
```

```html
<textarea id="typeword" class="pre" placeholder="Исходный текст"></textarea>
<textarea id="copyword" class="post" placeholder="Перенесённый текст"></textarea>
```